# I'm trying to create an array from ES class arguments but I'm getting an empty Array, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, args

Consider this code for this scenario of creating an Array with value of "sideLength" and for "sides" times within this ES class, but I'm keep getting an empty array!! here is codepen [link](https://codepen.io/bappyasif/pen/LYZZZpJ)

```
class ShapeNew {
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  tryArray() {
    let sides_array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sides; i++) {
      sides_array = sides_array.push(this.sideLength);
    }
    return sides_array;
  }
  newPerimeter() {
    let peri = this.tryArray();
    console.log(peri.reduce((sum, accum) => sum + accum));
  }
}
let new_square = new ShapeNew("square", 4, 5);
new_square.newPerimeter();
```

All I'm trying to do is convert 4 into [5,5,5,5], how do I do that?

Thanks in advance for looking into this, I appreciate it :)

Comment: `sides_array.push(this.sideLength);` instead of redefining the array on every round.

Comment: @Teemu that was easy, thanks :)

can it be improved , like, without doing it from local variable than with args?

Comment: `return new Array(4).fill(this.sideLength);` would do the trick without any variables.

Comment: @abappy what's the purpose of the method `tryArray()`? it just returns a new array of as much sides of side length

Comment: @Teemu that should be `return new Array(this.sides).fill(this.sideLength);`

Comment: @SaymoinSam It can be either way, though if the amount of the sides in a square will change in the future, then your way is more exact.

Comment: @Teemu Yup but why are you hard coding the number of items  to 4? it should be dynamic

Comment: @Teemu this looks even better, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @abappy If you're going to create other shapes than squares, then go with the variation SaymoinSam suggested.

Comment: @Teemu Okay, thanks to both of you anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this

```
sides_array.push(this.sideLength);
```

Not this

```
sides_array = sides_array.push(this.sideLength);
```

Because `Array.push()` does not return anything.

Comment: *Because Array.push() does not return anything.* not exactly, `Array.push()` returns the new length of the array

Comment: @SaymoinSam thanks, for your clarification. It helped me understand much clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to the variable `sides_array` the returned value of pushing a new element which is the new length, instead just push the element each time

```js
class ShapeNew {
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  tryArray() {
    let sides_array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sides; i++) {
      sides_array.push(this.sideLength);
    }
    return sides_array;
  }
  newPerimeter() {
    let peri = this.tryArray();
    console.log(peri.reduce((sum, accum) => sum + accum));
  }
}
let new_square = new ShapeNew("square", 4, 5);
new_square.newPerimeter();
```

But I was wondering, if all what you wanted to do is just calculating the perimeter, then why don't you just multiply the sides with side length?!

```js
class ShapeNew {
  constructor(name, sides, sideLength) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sides = sides;
    this.sideLength = sideLength;
  }
  perimeter() {
    return this.sideLength * this.sides;
  }
}

let new_square = new ShapeNew("square", 4, 5);
console.log(new_square.perimeter());
```

Comment: Yeah, you're exactly right :) I could have, thanks again for this new approach :)